# iPhone saving multiple objects in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My basic data model:

(one) Category has (many) Items

My code (minified):

```
item = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

category = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[item setValue:category forKey:@"category"];

[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]
```

Is there any problem with doing the above? I am getting some very odd results in regards to what is saving and what isn't and just wanted to know if I am doing something clearly wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What result do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: This code is fine. If you do have a problem, which is not possible to tell from your current question ("very odd results" is not helpful) it is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no you are not doing anything clearly wrong in that code. That code looks fine.

Post some info about the strange results and you might get some more feedback.